# How do I do prediction with Zero-Inflated regression model?

Tags: r, output, regression, prediction, poisson

I am fitting a Zero-Inflation Poisson regression model, this it the summary output:

```
Call:
zeroinfl(formula = m ~ lcounts | 1, dist = "poisson")

Pearson residuals:
       Min         1Q     Median         3Q        Max 
   -22.090    -13.297     -4.686     26.634 115088.430 

Count model coefficients (poisson with log link):
                    Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)        3.788e+00  5.901e-04  6418.7   <2e-16 ***
lcountsf           5.306e-01  7.644e-05  6941.9   <2e-16 ***
lcountsm           1.095e-02  4.031e-05   271.6   <2e-16 ***
lcountso           1.999e-01  8.525e-05  2345.0   <2e-16 ***
lcountss           7.289e-02  4.432e-05  1644.8   <2e-16 ***
lcountst           3.916e-02  4.258e-05   919.6   <2e-16 ***

Zero-inflation model coefficients (binomial with logit link):
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  -6.6645     0.4011  -16.62   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1 

Number of iterations in BFGS optimization: 14 
Log-likelihood: -1.965e+07 on 7 Df
```

I was wandering how can I perform prediction with this kind of model? 
With a normal `glm` is just `predict(model, newdata)`.
Is there a spefic command to do it?

Comment: Just pass a `zeroinfl` model to `predict`, like you would for a `glm`. The method is described in the documentation [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pscl/versions/1.5.2/topics/predict.zeroinfl).

Comment: you just need to do what you descibe  predict(model, newdata) , as mentionned here: https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/zip/

Comment: Thanks @Lyngbakr! Do you have an idea why in the summary of my model in the part `Zero-inflation model coefficients (binomial with logit link)` i just have the intercept and not all the covariates?

Comment: you have specified an intercept-only zero-inflation model (there is a `1` to the right of the bar in the formula, which means you are specifying a constant model for zero-inflation). There are a **lot** of things that look weird/worrying about this model output: if you have 7 residual df (see the log-likelihood statement at the end), that suggests you have 15 total data points; the Pearson residual distribution is extreme; you are estimating a very small zero-inflation level ...

Comment: @BenBolker, what do you mean by "e Pearson residual distribution is extreme; you are estimating a very small zero-inflation level "? Do you suggest to fit just a general Poisson Regression?

Comment: yes, as far as I can tell it looks like you probably don't need the zero-inflation. But I am worried about the model more generally. You appear to have a very small data set but very significant differences among groups without large differences in the mean.  That suggests something else is wrong.  Am I right that your full data set has 15 observations?  Are you really fitting raw count data and not some kind of scaled count data? Can you post your data?

Comment: My dataset is almost 5000 observations, the response variable is a count variable (with some zeros) and the 5 explanatory variables are log-transformed count variables. @BenBolker

Comment: I guess the df that `zeroinfl` is reporting is the *model* df rather than the residual df. OK.  In that case results make somewhat more sense.  You might as well keep the zero-inflation (although it might not make much difference).  Do check diagnostics for the residuals though!